# ASP.NET: images broken when combining URL Rewriting, asp:ImageButton and html base tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, url-rewriting

I'm using URL Rewriting under ASP.NET 4 (using ISAPI_Rewrite) and I'm finding that that some of my images are not loading as .NET does not seem to understand I'm using an html BASE tag (pretty standard and essential when doing URL Rewriting):

eg in my development environment I have:

```
<base href='http://localhost/venuefinder/Website/'></base>
```

and on my pages I have:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/button.gif" />
```

On the home page of the site (http://localhost/venuefinder/Website/) this works fine, however on a page that uses URL rewriting, the image does not work:

```
/venuefinder/Website/venues/ashton_gate_stadium/V18639/
```

..as the browser is trying to load:

```
http://localhost/images/buttons/search-button.gif
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost/venuefinder/Website/venues/images/buttons/search-button.gif
```

This is happening because .NET is rendering the button as:

```
src="../../../images/buttons/search-button.gif"
```

...which is incorrect.

Is there any way I can correct this problem so that .NET renders the correct src attribute for the image? (without all the ../../../ etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `~/` in images, create a virtual folder in IIS called `images` which maps to your images directory (so: `http://localhost/images` => `c:\myproject\somesubdir\content\images`). Then you can use

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/button.gif" />
```

We do this for all our website content items (script / images / css).

If you use `<base>` in HTML, the browser takes the given url as base for images that begin with `/`. So in your case you can just ditch the tilde.

---

One of the advantages of the Virtual Directory approach however is that you never have to bother about the url structure again, neither in .NET or JS:

```
ScriptHelper.RegisterScript("/js/somefile.js")
```

or

```
$().append('<img src="/images/file.jpg"/>')
```

Comment: I don't really see how this would fix the problem? I thought a virtual directory would simply allow me to store the images somewhere else, but are you saying it actually changes the behaviour of .NET itself?

Comment: Or you're perhaps suggesting I really do create it a the root level, in which case I don't see how this would work if I have more one website with this problem? I can't map localhost/images/ for more than one website (and I have around 30 websites I develop).

Comment: You can map /yourwebsite/images, and set the base-path in your page to http://localhost/yourwebsite; then you can still use `/`. As the browser now takes /localhost/yourwebsite as it's base for `/` prefixed images.